# Find a list of Files using Sharepoint REST API

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-rest-api

This seems to be an aloof question that I can't track down anywhere including here, so I am going to try again to see if someone has a solution.  I have a SharePoint 2013 instance that I use the REST API for doing content searches and return to my React front end to display.  This works great.  However, I now have a problem when I need to only search for a list of specific documents across the whole site not just in a directory or specific list.  I can do a content search using the /_api/search/query?queryText="" just fine, but I want to construct the querytext of this API endpoint to only search for doucments within the list I provide.

For example, if I am looking for three documents:

1. Foo.txt
2. Bar.doc
3. Foobar.pdf

I only want these documents and corresponding data (like the RedirectEmbedURL, etc that I get using the search api) not the /_api/web/lists/getByTitle method.

Is there a way to format the querystring to return only specific files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To retrieve the list you need to know the Site path and the library name.

Also you need operators to work with filters

[**Operators**](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests#odata-query-operators-supported-in-the-sharepoint-rest-service)

**Retrieve all Files inside a list:**
https:////_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('')/Items?$expand=File

*example:*

```
https://domain-example.com/sites/site1/site2/etc/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('listtitle')/Items?$expand=File
```

*Here are some examples of filters*:

*To **filter by name** you need to expand "FieldValuesAsText" and filter by the property "FileLeafRef"*
**Example here:**

```
https://[site]/web/Lists/GetByTitle('[library_name]')/Items?$filter=substringof('[TEXT_TO_SEARCH]',Title) or substringof('[TEXT_TO_SEARCH]',FileLeafRef)&$expand=File,FieldValuesAsText
```

*I'm also filtering by Title as I don't know if the user needs the title or the name with the extension.*

**Filter StartsWith**:

```
https://domain-example.com/sites/site1/site2/etc/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('listtitle')/Items?$expand=File&$filter=startswith(Title,'Foo')
```

**Filter "Contains" (substringof)**

```
https://domain-example.com/sites/site1/site2/etc/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('listtitle')/Items?$expand=File&$filter=substringof('T15', Title)
```

**Filter "Search with Related key (ex1 in this case)":  (substringof)**

```
https://domain-example.com/sites/site1/site2/etc/_api/Web/lists/GetByTitle('listtitle')/Items?$expand=FieldValuesAsText&$filter=substringof('BES10GHC10BB001', ex1)
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Here is what I finally came up with to search only the titles:

https://[sharepoint site]/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&rowlimit=10&refinementfilters='Title:or("40c91e71-d3b6-4b23-b034-50f6dca76649"%2c"eb5d0a99-d619-411d-9b0e-abcd5430d7da")'&clienttype='ContentSearchRegular'

I am now putting in the Select properties I need to get the data I want.  I was stuck on the Refinement Filters and trying to use them to get the titles.

Comment: @john I want to find files by the key "Name" within a Library inside a site but I don't know how to do it, I've tried: "https://[sharepoint site]/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle([LIBNAME]')/Items?$expand=File&$filter=substringof('filename.doc', File/Name)" But I'm getting the error that the column "File" doesn't exists. :(

Comment: @john Found It, updating answer

Answer (score 2):

I just use:

```
https://<domain>/sites/<list-title>/_api/files
```

It includes Url, Name and "childrenCount" to filter folders.

You can use logic in the request to filter.